# Read unix files in java web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, web

I need to have a web application in java(preferably) to login to a particular unix server say (xxx.pr.s.com) using username and password.and to read a particular file in that server . Isa there any java library to achieve the same.

Thanks.

Comment: @jeyaprakash See this [sample program](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15332487/1516759) in this thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Java Secure Channel (JSCH) is what you're looking for.  It will allow you to ssh into the OS http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Comment: SSH has a number of different ways the file could be transferred.  The OP only wanted to "read" the file, he can do this with SSH then send a command to echo the contents of the file over ssh.  I admit this is a dirty solution but there isn't enough information to make any further assumptions.